# Trying to dynamically print a list of servers and when i click on one i would like to display what i just clicked on

Tags: javascript, php, html

Like the title says i am trying to dynamically load a list of servers and when i click on one in a drop down list i would like to alert which one i just clicked on. I do have it loading all the servers perfectly fine im just hung up on finding the one i clicked on.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4" style="width: 300px;">
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($userguilds); $x++) {
            if ($userguilds[$x]->owner == 1) {
                //print_r($userguilds[$x]->name);
                echo "<h6 onclick='myFunction()' id='" . $userguilds[$x]->name . "'>
                        <li >
                            <a href='#' >" . $userguilds[$x]->name . "</a>
                        </li>
                    </h6>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                // Try to get name of what i just clicked on an alert it
            }
        </script>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` as an argument to the function, then it can access the `id` property.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4" style="width: 300px;">
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($userguilds); $x++) {
            if ($userguilds[$x]->owner == 1) {
                //print_r($userguilds[$x]->name);
                echo "<h6 onclick='myFunction(this)' id='" . $userguilds[$x]->name . "'><li ><a href='#' >" . $userguilds[$x]->name . "</a></li></h6>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            function myFunction(element) {
                console.log(element.id);
            }
        </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow phenominal, great job! Thank you so much for your help!